# Coordinating Conjunctions + Conjunctive Adverbs

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions, conjunction-reduction

> 1- Alexander II was an obscure commander ***but nevertheless*** interesting
>   Scottish king.
>
> (Full version: Alexander II was an obscure commander ***but nevertheless***
>   Alexander II was an interesting Scottish king
>
> 2- The defendant was depressed ***and therefore*** not fully
>   responsible for her own actions.
>
> (Full version: The defendant was depressed ***and therefore*** the
>   defendant was not fully responsible for her own actions.)

In the examples above, we use reduction in conjuction clause by omitting "subject and the auxillary verb (be) . Can I do the same reduction if I use just a conjunctive adverb in the sentence? As:

> 1a- Alexander II was an obscure commander, ***nevertheless*** interesting
>   Scottish king.
>
> 2a- The defendant was depressed, ***therefore*** not fully responsible
>   for her own actions.

Comment: The full version of your first example is ungrammatical. *Alexander II was **an obscure** but nevertheless Alexander II was **an interesting** Scottish king.*. In order for that to be grammatical, something like the very first (where an adjective and noun follows *nevertheless*) is required, or a noun needs to directly follow *obscure*.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have edited the post. What do you think about the rest of my question?

Comment: The part that comes after the conjunction has to be a valid complement of the verb - the problem with 1 is that you can't say *Alexander II was interesting Scottish king*. In other words you have omitted more than the subject and the verb (is it really an auxiliary verb here)? For me the versions without *and* and *but* need semicolons rather than commas. It is still possible to reduce the second clause in the same way, but I'd say this is done less frequently.

Comment: The defendant was depressed; therefore not fully responsible for her own actions or The defendant was depressed; therefore, not fully responsible for her own actions. Is each version correct?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the question as you originally wrote it: yes, you can omit the coordinating conjunction, "and" and still have an idiomatic, grammatical sentence.

Sentence 2 can be correctly rewritten as sentence 2a.

Sentence 1, as you originally had it should have had a pair of commas to set off the parenthetical remark, "but nevertheless interesting". In other words:

> 1- Alexander II was an obscure, but nevertheless interesting, Scottish
>   king.
>
> (Then the full version would be: Alexander II was an obscure Scottish
>   king, but nevertheless Alexander II was an interesting Scottish king.)

That can be condensed down, as you originally proposed, to:

> 1a- Alexander II was an obscure, nevertheless interesting, [but note that
>   second comma] Scottish king.

I think an extra complication was introduced along with adding the noun, "commander" in your correction to sentence 1, when all that was needed was a couple of commas, and that has led to some new grammatical problems with the edited versions of sentence 1.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do the same reduction if I use just a conjunctive adverb in the
>   sentence?

Coordinating conjunctions differ from conjunctive adverbs. When you omit the subject and the auxiliary verb (be) you are using the parallelism; while the conjunctive adverbs should only exist in a complete sentence.

> 1a- Alexander II was an obscure commander, nevertheless interesting
>   Scottish king.
>
> 2a- The defendant was depressed, therefore not fully responsible for
>   her own actions.

Here are the correct and compact corrections:

> 1a- Alexander II was an obscure commander; nevertheless, he is an interesting
>   Scottish king.
>
> 2a- The defendant was depressed; therefore she is not fully responsible for
>   her own actions.

Comment: Thank you. What you are saying is contradicting with other native speaker's opinion on this issue, though. I am confused.